# comparing length of dictionary in jinja flask template

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, jinja2, template-engine

I pass the dictionary errs to a jinja template for flask server:

```
{% if  not errs|length  equals 0  %}
```

But, the following error occurs:

TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got 'equals'

I tried various combinations but keep getting different errors, so how to compare length of a dictionary in the template if construct?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This works for me (Jinja 2.7):

```
{% if {}|length == 0 %}
    is zero
{% endif %}
```